# Latency Between WLAN and LAN

Tags: networking

I am trying to find the latency between WLAN and LAN in same network,When I am sending data packet from WLAN to LAN its latency(5ms) is much lesser than sending data packet through LAN to WLAN(20 ms),Can someone explain me Why is it happening?

Comment: There can be a number of reasons why this happen. Latency on networks can be caused by various different reasons.

Comment: Can you tell me few of those reasons

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi clients can switch off their transceivers to conserve power. For that purpose, they send a specific flag to the access point (AP) when they go to sleep. This causes the AP  to buffer all frames until the clients signals that the slumber is over.

So when sending ping packets in downlink direction (from LAN to Wi-Fi client), there may be the need to buffer the Wi-Fi frame containing the ping on AP until the Wi-Fi client comes back from sleep.

When sending a frame in uplink direction (from Wi-Fi client to LAN), the Wi-Fi client makes sure to wake up its transceiver whenever it needs to send a frame. So there is no additional delay, as APs usually do not go to sleep, either.

In a more crowded environment with lots of traffic and interference, more factors come into play (search for Clear Channel Assessment/CCA if you want to learn how access to the medium is coordinated) and the difference in up- and downlink delay will be leveled out.